# Distance between linear transformed points

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose I have two points $x_1$ and $x_2$, both from $\mathbb{R}^n$, and an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with integer entries. Is it possible to say anything about the distance between the points $p_1=Ax_1$ and $p_2=Ax_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$, as a function of the distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$? I suppose that it should be possible to say something sensible along the lines of

> If $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert<\epsilon $ then $\Vert p_1-p_2\Vert<f(\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert)$

However, I am not able to come up with any good expressions for the function $f$.
I do not have any particular metric in mind, so it's fine to assume the distance is teh Euclidean distance.

Comment: this is what matrix norms are for...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm
look at Matrix norms induced by vector norms